# replacement keyup function in mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I'm using this example script to filter content from a large html table .
http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/

It works great on desktop but it does not detect the keyup function in mobile devices .

I tried to change
`$('#search').keyup(function() {` to `$('#search').input(function() {`
but still not working.

Is there any alternative to make it work on phones?

Answer (score 0):

There is a example with vanila JS.
This should work on mobile.

```js
search.addEventListener('input', function(e) { title.innerText = this.value });
```

```html
<h1 id="title"></h1>  
<input type="text" id="search">
```